# how to switch to user account to access bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, user-accounts

all.need your help there~
In GCP vm instance, i use nodejs write code,try to access dataset, I want use email account, and try this way to set account:

```
//in linux run commond to set the account
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmdStr = 'gcloud config set account email@mmm.com';
exec(cmdStr, function (err, stdout, srderr) {
if(err) {
   console.log(err);
} else { 
   console.log(out);
  }
});
```

and when I run it, it uses a service account to access a big query.
Anyone can help me to switch the account from the service account to an email account?

Answer (score 0):

Running ‘gcloud config set account email@mmm.com’ [“sets the specified property in your active configuration”](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) and does NOT authenticate your Cloud SDK with email@mmm.com.

You can authenticate Cloud SDK by executing ‘gcloud auth init’ from the command line. For more information please refer to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/). Note that this does not authenticate the BigQuery API as explained below, instead this authenticates the GCloud SDK command line tools such as [bq command line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-command-line) and gcloud commands.

To authenticate your Google Cloud API calls, you need to use a service account key. Please refer to steps 3-4 in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) for detailed steps on achieving this in node.js.

You cannot authenticate API calls with an email account. The workaround is to use service account impersonation, please refer to [documentation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/impersonating-users-with-google-cloud-platform-service-accounts-ba762db09092) for further explanation.